# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy - If not parent term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy with two levels of terms.

- Parent term

  - Child term
  - Child term
- Parent term

  - Child term
  - Child term
- Parent term (no children)

I'm using a custom archive.php template with some HTML that I only want to display on terms without child terms.

Here's what I've tried...

```
$taxonomy = 'custom_tax';
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array( 'parent' => $term->term_id ) );

if(!$children) {
    echo '<p>HTML only terms without child terms</p>';
}
```

This works if it's a Child term but not on a Parent term with no children!

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_term_children` for checking there is have any child term or not.

```
$taxonomy = 'custom_tax';
$term = get_queried_object();
if ( count( get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) === 0 ) {
     echo '<p>HTML only terms without child terms</p>';
}
else
{
    echo '<p>HTML only terms with child terms</p>';
}
```